# Is this integral bounded below by a positive number given that a similar integral is?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I feel as if I ought to know this, but it's escaping me. Let $dA$ denote the usual Lebesgue area measure in $\Bbb C$.

Let's say I have a function $\phi$ which is nonnegative and in $L^{\infty}(\Bbb D)$, where $\Bbb D$ is the unit disc (or some finite Borel measure space).

Let $g_a(z)$ be a function which is square integrable on the disc for all $a \in \Bbb D$ and holomorphic for all $z \in \Bbb D$ for all $a \in \Bbb D$, and suppose we know there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that

$$\int_{\Bbb D} \sqrt{\phi(z)} |g_a(z)|^2 dA(z) > \delta$$ for all $a \in \Bbb D$. Does there exist some other $\delta'>0$ also independent of $a$ such that

$$\int_{\Bbb D} \phi(z) |g_a(z)|^2 dA(z) > \delta'$$ for all $a \in \Bbb D$?

Notice that at its heart, this is really an elementary measure theory question about the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: You can prove this by Hoelder inequality if the family of functions $g_a$ is bounded in $L^2(D)$.

Comment: You mean if $g_a$ are all in $L^2$ of the disc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\|g_a\|_{L^2(D)}\le M$ for all $a$, then the claim can be proven by Holder inequality:
$$
\delta \le \int_D \sqrt\phi |g_a|^2 \le \|g_a\|_{L^2(D)} \|\sqrt\phi |g_a|\|_{L^2(D)} \le M \cdot\left( \int_D \phi |g_a|^2 \right)^{1/2}
$$